# How can I get two date vectors into MATLAB format using datenum

Tags: matlab

new to MATLAB, and I would like to take two vectors `year` and `month` and put them into one `date` vector in matlab format using datenum(). I've tried doing this from the documentation but I'm still not quite sure how to go about doing this. What I had was:

```
date = datenum(year, month);
```

This gave me an error, if anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error you received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the input to datenum should be a `string` or a `cell-array`, so you can do something like:

```
year = [1989;1990];
month = [10;11];
input = cellstr(num2str([year,month]));
date = datenum (input,'yyyy   mm')
```

note you need to write the correct parsing format for your date string.

```
date =

  726742
  727138

formatOut = 'mmmm-dd-yyyy';
datestr(date,formatOut,'local')

ans = 

  October -01-1989
  November-01-1990
```

I think you can also enter numerical inputs into `datenum`, but I am not sure if it accepts vectors - I have the 2010b version at office and it does not work.

Comment: In that case, please accept the answer as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to convert numbers to strings and back as in @gameofthrows's answer - these are incredibly costly operations. You can use undocumented mex function `datenummx` (which you can spot if you inspect `datenum` source):

```
year = [1989;1990];
month = [10;11];

day = ones(size(year));
datenums = datenummx(year, month, day);
```

That gives an impressive **~86x** speedup (Matlab 2013b) over the other solution proposed here:

```
>> tic; for i=1:1e6, datenums = datenummx(year, month, ones(size(year))); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 3.286964 seconds.
>> tic; for i=1:1e6, input = cellstr(num2str([year,month])); datenums = datenum (input,'yyyy   mm'); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 283.356511 seconds.
```

There should probably be a general word of caution here that it could break in a future release, but this function has been around for half a decade, and the performance benefit clearly outweighs other concerns.